# Validação de campos WebForms

Tags: javascript, c#, webforms

Estou montando uma página de cadastro com `webforms`, preciso fazer as validações dos campos, mas não sei se é melhor fazê-la pelo próprio método `onclick` do botão de gravação *(via c#)* ou se existe alguma forma de chamar uma função `javascript` para validar antes de permitir a gravação por este meu método `onclick`.

O que devo fazer?

Comment: Uma boa validação sempre é no servidor ou seja no seu C#, mas validações no lado do cliente torna a aplicação mais intuitiva, uma vez que você não precisa ir no servidor para verificar se o campo esta correto antes de lança uma exceção. Por isso faço nos dois lado se possível.

Comment: recomendo fazer uma "flag" para a validação em script mesmo, jogando todas as condições (if) caso não passe em alguma ele retorna falso, caso ele passe em todos os ifs (os campos apresentados) ele retorna true e aplica o restante do processo de gravação...

Comment: Use Validation Controls. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/debza5t0.aspx Você pode validar desde campos obrigatórios até expressões regulares. Um bom artigo, em inglês:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/49527/How-to-Use-the-ASP-NET-Validation-Control-to-Valid

Answer (score 1):

Boa tarde, Pode colocar uma validação ao clicar em um botão, o evento do botão é o `OnClick();` ao clicar no botão é validado cada campo.
EX:

```
//Se não estiver nulo ou vazio.

IF  (String.IsNullOrEmpty(Textbox1.Text)){

//Mensagem de aviso que avisando que está vazio.

}
```

No caso de uma validação no lado do cliente, pode-se utilizar o metodo, `OnLostFocus();` para cada campo de entrada de dados. Ao perder o foco do controle é feito uma verificação.

Answer (score 1):

Essse script foi de um projetinho de teste que eu criei faz um tempo, mas deve ajudar um pouco acredito eu.

Script de validação (Email, cpf, checkbox, Data, senha, telefone e etc)

```
function valida()
{
        var info = "";
        corErro ="#ccff99";
    corAcerto="#FFFFFF";

        // Validação de Nome
    var nome = document.getElementById("nome");
    var strNome = nome.value;
    if ((strNome.length < 6) || (strNome.length > 30)) {
        info += " - O nome deve ter entre 6 e 30 caracteres. \n"; 
                nome.style.backgroundColor = corErro;
                nome.focus();
    } else {
    nome.style.backgroundColor = corAcerto;
    }

        // Validação de Data
        var aData = document.getElementById("data");
    strData = aData.value;
    vetData = strData.split("/");

    if (vetData.length != 3){
        info += " - Erro na data, não possui dia/mês/ano. \n";
                aData.style.backgroundColor = corErro;
                aData.focus();
    } else {
        dia = vetData[0];
        mes = vetData[1];
        ano = vetData[2];
        if (isNaN(dia) || isNaN(mes) || isNaN(ano)) {
            info += " - Existem erro nos valores para dia/mês/ano. \n";
                        aData.style.backgroundColor = corErro;
                        aData.focus();
        } else {

            intAno = parseInt(ano);
            intMes = parseInt(mes);
            intDia = parseInt(dia);

            if ((intAno < 1900) || (intAno > Date().getFullYear)){
                info += " - O ano deve estar entre 1900 e hoje. \n";
                                aData.style.backgroundColor = corErro;
                                aData.focus();
            } else {
                if((intMes < 1) || (intMes) > 12){
                    info += " - O mês deve estar entre 1 e 12. \n"; 
                                       aData.style.backgroundColor = corErro;
                                       aData.focus();
                                    } else {

                    var bissexto = ((intAno % 4) == 0);
                    var intFim = 30;
                    switch (intMes){
                        case 1, 3, 5, 7, 8, 10 ,12:
                                                    intFim = 31;
                                                        break;
                        case 4, 6, 9, 11:
                                                    intFim = 30;
                                                        break;
                        case 2:
                                                    if(bissexto){
                                                        intFim = 29;
                                                                } else{
                                                                intFim = 28;
                                                                      }
                                                                break;
                                                        }
                                            if((intDia < 1) || (intDia> intFim)) {
                                                    info += " - O dia deve estar entre 1 e " + intFim + " para o mês/ano. \n";
                                                        aData.style.backgroundColor = corErro;
                                                        aData.focus();
                                                    } else {
                                                        aData.style.backgroundColor = corAcerto;
                                                                                    }//d5
                                        }//d4
                                }//d3
                        }//d2   
                }//d1

                 //Validação de CPF
                 var cpf = document.getElementById("cpf");
                 strcpf = cpf.value;
                 strcpf = strcpf.replace(".","");
                 strcpf = strcpf.replace(".","");
                 strcpf = strcpf.replace("-","");

                 if (isNaN(strcpf)){
                     info+= " - CPF inválido.(contém letras) \n"
                     cpf.style.background = corErro;
                     cpf.focus();
                 } else {
                 if (strcpf == '' || strcpf.length != 11)
                 {
                     info+= " - É obrigatório o preenchimento do CPF.(Caso preenchido, verifique se há caracteres ou números digitados de forma incorreta) \n";
                     cpf.style.backgroundColor = corErro;
                     cpf.focus();
                 } else {
                if (   strcpf == "00000000000"
                    || strcpf == "11111111111"
                    || strcpf == "22222222222"
                    || strcpf == "33333333333"
                    || strcpf == "44444444444"
                    || strcpf == "55555555555"
                    || strcpf == "66666666666"
                    || strcpf == "77777777777"
                    || strcpf == "88888888888"
                    || strcpf == "99999999999")
                 {
                   info += " - CPF inválido. \n";
                   cpf.style.backgroundColor = corErro;
                   cpf.focus();
                    } else { 
                        var Soma;
                        var Resto;
                        Soma = 0;
                        for (i = 1; i <= 9; i++)
                            Soma = Soma + parseInt(strcpf.substring(i-1, i)) * (11 - i);
                        Resto = (Soma * 10) % 11;
                        if (Resto != parseInt (strcpf.substring(9, 10)))
                        {
                            info+= " - CPF inválido. \n";
                            cpf.style.backgroundColor = corErro;
                            cpf.focus();
                        } else {
                            Soma = 0;
                            for (i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
                                Soma = Soma + parseInt(strcpf.substring(i-1, i)) *(12 - i);
                                Resto = (Soma * 10) % 11;
                                if (Resto != parseInt (strcpf.substring(10, 11)))
                                    {
                                    info+=" - CPF inválido. \n";
                                    cpf.style.backgroundColor = corErro;
                                    cpf.focus();
                                        } else {
                                            cpf.style.backgroundColor = corAcerto;
                                                }//d5
                                }//d4
                            }//d3
                        }//d2
                    }//d1

        //Validação de Telefone
        var tel = document.getElementById("tel");
        strtel = tel.value;
        strtel = strtel.replace ("-","");
        if (isNaN(strtel)){
            info+= " - Telefone inválido. \n ";
            tel.style.backgroundColor = corErro;
            tel.focus();
                } else {
                        if (strtel == '' || strtel.length < 8){
                            info+= " - É obrigatório o preenchimento do telefone. \n";
                            tel.style.backgroundColor = corErro;
                            tel.focus();
                            } else {
                                tel.style.backgroundColor = corAcerto;
                                   }
                        }

        // Validação do E-mail
        var email = document.getElementById("email");
        var contnum;
        var contlet;
        stremail = email.value;
        if (stremail == '')
        {
            info+= " - Preencha o campo do email. \n"
            email.style.backgroundColor = corErro;
            email.focus();
        } else {
            email.style.backgroundColor = corAcerto;
        }

        //Validação de Senha
        var senha = document.getElementById("senha");
        var numeros = "0123456789";
        var letras = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvxyz";
        var contlet;
        var contnum;
        strsenha = senha.value;
        strsenha = strsenha.toLowerCase();
        contlet = 0;
        contnum = 0;
        if ( '' != strsenha ){
                    for (i = 0; i < strsenha.length; i++)
                    {
                        if(numeros.indexOf(strsenha.charAt(i),0)!= -1)
                        {
                        contnum++;
                        }
                        if(letras.indexOf(strsenha.charAt(i),0)!= -1)
                        {
                        contlet++;
                        }
                        }
                    }
        if (strsenha = "" || contnum < 2 || contlet < 4)
        {
            info+= " - Obrigatório o preenchimento da senha. (Caso preenchido, verificar o mínimo requerido: 4 letras e 2 números \n";
            senha.style.backgroundColor = corErro;
            senha.focus();
        } else {
            senha.style.backgroundColor = corAcerto;
        }

        // Validação do checkList
        var op1 = document.getElementById("op1");
    var op2 = document.getElementById("op2");
    var op3 = document.getElementById("op3");
    var op4 = document.getElementById("op4");
    if(
        ( ! op1.checked)
        &&
        ( ! op2.checked)
        &&
        ( ! op3.checked)
        &&
        ( ! op4.checked)
        ){
        info += " - Deve ser selecionado uma preferencia pelo menos.\n";
                op1.focus();
            }

        // Final descrevendo os Erros listados em Alert
        if (info.length > 0){
        alert("Erros detectados: \n\n" + info);
                    return false;
                            } else {
                                return true;
                                    }
}
```

O html necessita conter isto pelo menos

```
<form onsubmit="return valida();" id="form1" method="get" action="CadastroConfirmado.html">
//Campos das validações aqui!
<button type="submit" id="btninclui" value="">Pronto!</button>
</form>
```

O botão após clicado, joga o onsubmit que está no form e em seguida executa a function de validação. A validação é feita por etapas, verificando campo a campo, caso algum campo não esteja correto ele guarda a informação do erro e no final da function ele verifica. Se houver alguma informação ele retorna false "anulando" o submit e informa o erro, caso não tenha nenhuma informação de erros ele retorna true e finaliza a execução do onsubmit.

Eu prefiro desta forma. O exemplo foi apenas uma demonstração, não sendo necessário compreender tudo o que citei, mas apenas uma referência que eu acho válido de mostrar para que torne bem claro como seria em script.